# Expecting Identifer Before Leftbrace

Tags: actionscript-3

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

var EmailFlashVariable = "aa@aa.com";
var AdfURLNavigator;
var AdfFlashVarsUtil;

mcButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
AdfURLNavigator.navigateToUrl(AdfFlashVarsUtil.getParameter("clickTAG") + ";cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=" + EmailFlashVariable);

var click_url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
if(click_url) {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(click_url), '_blank');
}
```

I have updated the script above and that cleared the error messages, but it will not show the parameter in URL instead I got this -

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at _10792MB_fla::MainTimeline/onClick()
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that for this >>> `:`

either `function ADFclicked(event:MouseEvent)`

or `function ADFclicked(event:MouseEvent):some_return_type`

Comment: Thank you very much (code updated). That cleared the error, but just got two new errors - "Call to a possibly undefined method navigateToUrl through a reference with static type String (same thing for getParameter).

Answer (score 1):

Functions return values.
Like Fygo wrote, when you put `:` at the end of a function signature in AS3, it expects you to put the type of the return value of the function there there.

Given that the function in question is an event listener, it should be `void`, meaning that "nothing" gets returned, so to speak.

So you either write what Fygo posted in the first half of his answer, or you write

```
function ADFclicked(event:MouseEvet):void
```

Please take a look at the [Documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

To use `navigateToURL` we do like this :

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(your_url_here))
```

For more details, take a look here : [navigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL())