# Transferring Variables in Query String

Tags: actionscript-3, clicktag

[image]

Im pulling my hair and Im still unable resolve this. Please tell me what did I do wrong with these codes?

Errors (NEW):

```
No Error, but display undefined;cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=aa@aa.com
```

CODE (UPDATED x3)-

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

var EmailFlashVariable = 'aa@aa.com'
var url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG + ';cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=' + EmailFlashVariable
var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url)

mcButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ADFclicked)
function ADFclicked(event:MouseEvent) { 
navigateToURL(url_request, '_blank')
```

I added

```
<param name="flashvars" value="clickTAG=http://www.freescoreonline.com">
```

In the generated HTML

Comment: You can continue in your first post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745119/expecting-identifer-before-leftbrace/

Comment: Nobody answered and decided to create a new thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show your swf in a html page, we use usually a code like this ( you can modify it of course, It's generated by Flash ) :

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="banner.swf">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">             
    <param name="flashvars" value="clickTAG=http://www.example.com">
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="banner.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="banner.swf">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
        <param name="flashvars" value="clickTAG=http://www.example.com">
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

You can see here that I used `flashvars` to pass params to our swf file (`banner.swf`), It's recommended to do that instead of `banner.swf?clickTAG=http://www.example.com` if you have the ability to use `flashvars`of course.

In AS3, to get a param that was passed by `flashvars` or using `?param=value`, we do like this : `root.loaderInfo.parameters.param`. In your case, here is what you can do :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent
import flash.net.URLRequest

var EmailFlashVariable:String = 'aa@aa.com'
var url:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG + ';cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=' + EmailFlashVariable
var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url)

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ADFclicked)
function ADFclicked(event:MouseEvent) { 
    navigateToURL(url_request, '_blank')    
}
```

I hope it's clear now, and please try always to explain your problem and to give all details for others to help you.

For flashVars, take a look here [swfs flashVars (by Adobe)](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html) and here for very good tutorial to better understand [AS3 flashVars](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/indexAs3.html).

Comment: Ok, no errors. Does the banner need to be on the server in order to display the correct URL parameter? Because its still showing `undefined;cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=aa@aa.com`

Comment: No, it is not an obligation, even locally it should pass the param. Did you use the proper HTML code ?

Comment: Yes I did. What I did I opened the HTML and inserted info in textfields and then nothing happened. Also if I open the SWF and inserted info in textfields and it showed `undefined;cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=aa@aa.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64353/discussion-between-akmozo-and-christian-luneborg).

Answer (score 0):

1. You are spelling `navigateToUrl` wrong, it is case sensitive:  `navigateToURL` (look at your import it's correct)
2. You haven't defined `getParameter` anywhere (that you've shown),  perhaps what you're looking to do here is `loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG` instead of `getParameter("clickTAG")`?

Try it this way and see if it works:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG + ";cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=" + EmailFlashVariable));
```

If you're still getting `undefined` as the result of `root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG`, then you've likely mis-spelled clickTAG, or the parameter isn't being passed to the swf properly.

---

Another way method you can try to get parameters directly from the page's url (since you don't show your html source it's impossible to know how to solve your issue).

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
var fullUrl:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(fullUrl.substr(fullUrl.lastIndexOf("?") + 1)); //the substring grabs only everything right of the ? in the url

navigateToURL(new URLRequest(vars.clickTAG + ";cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=" + EmailFlashVariable));
```

Comment: Like this `navigateToURL:loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG + ";cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=" + EmailFlashVariable;`

Comment: you need to wrap the url in a URLRequest object. I updated the answer

Comment: That fixed the error and now the URL parameter shows `undefined;cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=aa@aa.com` There are four textfields (First name, last name, email, and zip code) it didnt show the names and the zip code.

Comment: I updated the answer , your question doesn't address four textfields and why those matter.

Comment: You there? I need to know if you have updated the answer above, because it looks the same.

Comment: The difference is the `root` key word before loader info

Comment: I updated the code and still got the parameter URL `undefined;cppar=1&EmailURLVariable=aa@aa.com` Im not sure whats causing this and your suggestion is appreciated! Also the clickTAG spelled correct and how do I make sure the parameter is correctly passed to the SWF properly?

Comment: Update your question to Show your HTML code you use for the swf

Comment: I added another way you could potentially get the clickTAG. Again, without seeing your html source it's impossible to know what you need.

Comment: @akmozo - don't hijack other peoples answers

Comment: @LDMS, if you are speaking about my comment, I'm sorry man, I had no bad intention, it happened just like that. I'll remove it.